# identify emails in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to create identifiers for the emails in my inbox.

My original plan was to compare the:

- sender address,
- body, and
- subject of an email

to see if its unique, but I've realized that `Outlook.MailItem.Body` doesn't return the same result when called across different versions of Outlook.

I've tried `Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody` and `Outlook.MailItem.RTFBody`; but they have the same issue as `Outlook.MailItem.Body`

Aside from moving emails I've processed into another folder, is there a way to idenfiy unique emails that's supported across Outlook versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having problem with the body, decide what "unique emails" really means. Try to remove all non-alphanumeric characters before comparing any two message bodies.

Comment: This sorta works. I still have a problem with how links are extracted between the two versions.